# ¿Qué hacer con respuestas largas que podrían acortarse considerablemente?

Tags: discusión

Me he encontrado con preguntas que podrían responderse de forma sencilla en uno o dos párrafos pero cuyas respuestas son publicaciones tan largas que, aunque correctas y buenas, en mi opinión pierden utilidad porque la respuesta real queda *oculta* entre párrafos y más párrafos de texto, código e imágenes.

Se me ocurrió escribir respuestas cortas en esos casos, pero me encuentro con que el cuerpo de mi respuesta va a estar contenido, de una forma u otra, en el cuerpo de la respuesta larga, por lo que alguien podría considerarlas un "duplicado" o "resumen" de la respuesta larga (aunque realmente sean ambas citas de la documentación oficial).

¿Qué hacer en esos casos? ¿Publicar la respuesta corta de todos modos? ¿Editar la respuesta larga para añadir una versión [`tl;dr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR)? (algo posible si es una respuesta de wiki, pero que puede llevar a conflicto si no lo es) ¿No hacer nada?

Comment: Como usuario a quien le gusta tanto leer como escribir respuestas largas, estoy totalmente de acuerdo con publicar aparte ([respuesta de Rubén](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3363/127)) pero quería agregar que hablando de un hipotético, habrá que ver el caso pero estaría algo reacio a que incluyeran un resumen en una respuesta mía (en muchos casos no sería el *estilo* que quería darle a la respuesta).

Comment: Además, odio la abreviación `TL;DR`... es en inglés, y yo no veo que se use a nivel profesional. ¿Por qué no `Resumen`, que es lo que se usa normalmente o en cualquier paper?

Comment: @Mariano técnicamente la edición iría en contra de la intención original del autor y si la encontrara en las revisiones la rechazaría

Comment: Posiblemente, pero creo que ahí depende mucho de cada caso concreto... Así como hablé de un hipotético, seguramente yo también tenga respuestas que se merezcan un resumen, y creo fervientemente que algo que mejora la calidad vale la pena como edición... En todos los casos, una edición sobre mis respuestas me parece algo muy bueno, pero en algunas volvería a editar para considerar la edición y llevarlo de nuevo a mi *estilo*.

Comment: Siempre se puede usar una solución de compromiso a lo que expone @Mariano. Puedes añadir un comentario diciendo: _Tu respuesta es excelente, pero un resumen la mejoraría mucho. Te importa que la edite para añadir el resumen? O prefieres hacerlo tu?_ De esa manera, el autor de la respuesta puede decidir. Si eligiese que su respuesta está bien como está, estarías legitimado para escribir tu propia respuesta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Escribe un comentario sugiriendo tu mejora para la respuesta, el resumen en este caso. Para eso son los comentarios.

Si tu comentario no es atendido y puedes escribir una respuesta mejor, hazlo.

Comment: Ok. Entonces sugieres dejar un comentario con el resumen en la respuesta larga. Si el resumen ocupa más de un comentario, ¿lo podría en 2-3?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro A veces basta con escribir "Excelente respuesta, sería mejor aún con un resumen al principio". Si además quieres ahorrarle al autor de la respuesta el trabajo de resumir pero no te cabe en 600 letras... pues sí, 2-3 comentarios sería una solución. Los puedes borrar cuando ponga el resumen, o cuando no lo haga y pongas tu respuesta.

Comment: Voy a probar a hacer algo como esto. Espero que no te moleste si copia el texto del comentario.

Answer (score 4):

Yo voy por publicar una respuesta breve porque

## Lo bueno y breve es doblemente bueno

Para tratar de minimizar el riesgo de recibir votos negativos podrías incluir una nota explicando tu motivación de publicar una respuesta breve.

Comment: Podría extenderme agregando razones pero entonces mi respuesta dejaría de ser breve ;)

Comment: este es una respuesta valida, y un comentario estupendo